# How can I record audio with the USB mic and record with the camera without having to sync them?

Tags: video, audio, microphone

I want to start making some YouTube videos, but I want to work with what I have for the moment, to see how it goes and learn using them for a while.

So I have a Behringer C1-U microphone and a Samsung NX1000 mirrorless camera. Is it possible to connect them both to the pc and record video and audio at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Samsung NX1000 can stream video to PC. So you can't "connect them both to the pc and record". You shall record first, and only then copy footage on the PC.

However some cameras have audio jacks inputs, to connect external microphone to them. And your Samsung NX1000 have one. But your microphone don't have audio jack output, so it outputs only digital signal. And your DSLR can receive only analog signal. So it is impossible to connect your microphone to your DSLR directly.

You need computer to convert digital signal to analog, and then connect it to your DSLR. It can be achieved with some kind of microcomputer like Raspberry Pi. Or, if you going to record only near your PC, you can plug your mic into PC, and then connect your PC's audio output to your DSLR's audio input. Maybe some settings on the PC should be adjusted for this to work properly. But it depends on your operating system.

After recording, do not forget to copy files from your DSLR to your PC.

Good Luck!